# Tree-like aliens invade Glasgow using mind-control

Tags: story-identification

The general idea of the book was that a race of aliens in the form of trees travelled through space visiting other worlds and using their ability to send their minds into the brains of the creatures living in these worlds so that they could explore without being intrusive or being discovered.

They arrived on Earth and sent their minds into the animals they could sense and one found his mind in the body of a teenage boy in Glasgow, Scotland around the mid-to-late sixties.

Having found himself in the teenager, he discovered the primitive mind of humans had him trapped and unable to return to his tree body.

The story is a little comic and deals with the teenager finding his way in life and how he deals with things like his mother and girls while worrying the others on the ship would be coming for him as he was happy not to rejoin them.

Answer (score 11):

This is "[The Krugg Syndrome](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2030027.Krugg_Syndrome)" by Angus McAllister.

- Set in Glasgow - Check
- Sentient tree/aliens - Check
- Trapped in the body of a teenager - Check

> The Krugg Syndrome (1988), is a mild-mannered and amusing tale of a country boy in the big City of Glasgow whose personality has been replaced by that of an Alien Krugg capable of Telepathy. The human condition proves more attractive than that of the Krugg (who are sentient trees), and the invader is happily assimilated into humanity. <sub><sup>[SF-Encylopedia](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/mcallister_angus)</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: the title doesn't ring any bells though it was a long time ago that I read it,

Comment: @rabtmac - Based on your description, I'd be very surprised if this wasn't it.

Comment: I think it probably is correct and I really cant thank you enough, ive found a copy on Amazon and off to buy it now thank you so so much absolutely brilliant after all these years I may have found the book ive been searching for thanks again

Comment: @rabtmac - No worries. As soon as you've confirmed it's definitely this, don't forget to upvote and mark this answer as "accepted".

Comment: And the quote from SF Encyclopedia provides more "check"s: 1) comical/amusing; 2) happy not to rejoin his own species. This can't possibly not be it.

Comment: :) It arrived on Christmas Eve and I can confirm that the Krugg Syndrome is the book ive been searching for all these years, thank you Richard you were spot on :)

Comment: @rabtmac - Don't forget to mark as "accepted" (by clicking the tick) to show that this was the right answer